# Evaluate : $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx$?

Tags: integration

> How to evaluate this?
>   $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx$$

I was given this integral saying that it can be solved, but when I couldn’t, I gave up and tried to give this input to integral calculator and as it turns out, even it wasn’t able to give an output in terms of any operator. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe the real question is to show that the integral converges.  That is an interesting exercise.

Comment: @GEdgar both showing that it converges and evaluating the integral would be very interesting

Comment: You have a logaritm in the form $log(1+ \alpha)$ so the most obvious thing is to find the McLaurin polynomials of the integrand function for $x\longrightarrow +\infty$ and $x \longrightarrow 0$.

Comment: The convolution theorem for the Mellin transform gives
$$\int_{\mathbb R^+} x^{-1}\ln(1 + x) \ln(1 + x^{-2}) \, dx =
\mathcal M^{-1}[F(p) F(p/2)/2](1), \\
F(p) = \mathcal M[x \mapsto \ln(1 + x)](p) =
\pi p^{-1} \csc \pi p,
\quad -1 < \operatorname {Re} p < 0.$$
The residues at $p = -2 k$ and $p = -2 k + 1$ give sums of $(-1)^k/(2 k^3)$ and $(-1)^{k - 1} \pi /(2 k - 1)^2$, which are not elementary.

Comment: possible duplicate here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730732/integral-i-int-0-infty-frac-ln1x-ln1x-2x-dx/3447541#3447541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx$$
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx=\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)\ln\left(1+{x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx$$
$$I=2\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln\left(1+{x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx-\frac{9}{4}\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln\left(x\right)}{x}\,dx={\pi}G-\frac{3}{8}\zeta(3)$$
These integrals are known
$$\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln\left(1+{x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx=-\frac{33}{32}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi}{2}G,\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln\left(x\right)}{x}\,dx=-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(3)$$

Comment: Can you please give a more detailed answer

Comment: $$\int_1^\infty x^{-1} \ln(1 + x) \ln(1 + x^{-2}) \, dx \neq
\int_0^1 x^{-1} \ln((1 + x)/2) \ln(1 + x^2) \, dx, \\
\int_0^\infty x^{-1} \ln(x) \ln(1 + x) \, dx = \infty.$$

Comment: @ MAxim OK correction